# Properties of the differential $df_x$ with respect to $x$

Tags: analysis, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

Given a smooth function $f:U \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$ and $x\in U$, let $df_x:\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$ be the differential of $f$ in the point $x$.
In the proof of a theorem I read the following passage

> Since $df_x$ is surjective (for hypothesis), then there exists an open neighborhood $V$ of $x$ such that $df_y$ is surjective for every $y\in V$

I don't understand the following passage. Why is it true? And what can be said in general for the function $x \mapsto df_x$?

Comment: The title doesn't match your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recall that a function $f: U \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$ is smooth if all its partial derivatives of all orders exist and are continuous.

Now let's focus on the Jacobian matrix $Df(x)$, which represents the derivative $df_x: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$. This matrix varies continuously with $x$ if $f$ is smooth. Specifically, if $x, y \in U$, then the difference between $Df(x)$ and $Df(y)$ can be made arbitrarily small by taking $y$ sufficiently close to $x$. This can be formally stated as follows: for all $x \in U$ and for all $\epsilon > 0$, there exists $\delta > 0$ such that if $\|y - x\| < \delta$ then $\|Df(y) - Df(x)\| < \epsilon$. Here $\|\cdot\|$ denotes some norm on the respective spaces, for example the sup norm for functions and the operator norm for matrices.

Now, suppose that the differential $df_x$ is surjective, which is equivalent to saying that $Df(x)$ has rank $m$. Since the rank of a matrix is lower semicontinuous, we have the following property: if $\{x_i\}$ is a sequence in $U$ such that $x_i \rightarrow x$ and each $Df(x_i)$ has rank $m$, then $Df(x)$ has rank $m$.

This can be used to show that there exists an open neighborhood $V$ of $x$ such that for every $y \in V$, $df_y$ is surjective. To prove this, fix $\epsilon > 0$, and let $V$ be the set of all $y \in U$ such that $\|y - x\| < \delta$, where $\delta$ is as above. By the continuity of $Df$, we have $\|Df(y) - Df(x)\| < \epsilon$ for all $y \in V$. Now, we claim that if $\epsilon$ is small enough, then $Df(y)$ has rank $m$ for all $y \in V$. If this were not the case, then there would be a sequence $\{y_i\} \subseteq V$ such that $Df(y_i)$ has rank less than $m$, and by the lower semicontinuity of the rank, this would imply that $Df(x)$ has rank less than $m$, a contradiction. Thus, $df_y$ is surjective for all $y \in V$.

Finally, regarding the function $x \mapsto df_x$, it's a function from $U$ to the space of $m \times n$ matrices, which is identified with the space of linear maps from $\mathbb{R}^n$ to $\mathbb{R}^m$. This function is smooth by the smoothness of $f$, and its differential at a point $x$ is a linear map from $\mathbb{R}^n$ to the space of $m \times n$ matrices, representing the rate of change of the Jacobian matrix as $x$ changes.